# Cannot set spinner's selected item

Tags: android

I want to set the selected item of a `spinner` :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Rue>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, db.getAllRues()); // db.getAllRues() has data
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ruePpale.setAdapter(adapter);
ruePpale.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(db.getRue(p.getDec_decoup_terri_code())), true); // p.getDec_decoup_terri_code() has data
```

Code of db.getRue :

```
public Rue getRue(String decoup_terri_code) {
    Rue r = new Rue();
    String[] columns = {"decoup_terri_code","decoup_terri_nom"};
    Cursor c = bd.query(T_DECOUP_TERRIT, columns, "decoup_terri_code=?", new String[]{decoup_terri_code}, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0 ) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        r.setDecoup_terri_code(c.getString(0));
        r.setDecoup_terri_nom(c.getString(1));
    }
    return r;
}
```

The problem is that at runtime the `spinner` does not scroll automatically to the desired item ! What is bad in my code ?

**-- EDIT --**

I overwrote the equals method in the class Rue :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Rue)) {
        return false;
    }
    Rue comp = (Rue) o;
    return (this.getDecoup_terri_code() == comp.getDecoup_terri_code() && this.getDecoup_terri_nom() == comp.getDecoup_terri_nom());
}
```

But the spinner does not select the item !

Comment: did you tried to debug your code? what returns `adapter.getPosition()` ? ... I'm pretty sure that -1 ... your item cannot be find with `List<Rue >.indexOf(item)` ...

Comment: yes it is -1 , so what is wrong ?

Comment: basic java conception ... -1 means [object was not found](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))  ... obviously [`List.indexOf`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L347) doesn't know how to compare(find equal) your objects

Comment: So I should inherit ArrayAdapter and implement the methods getCount , getPosition and getItem ?

Comment: no, java basics: override `equals` method in `Rue` class

Comment: check speciall things like other object is null or different class , return thisRueObject is equal otherRueObject (there is pleanty examples over the internet)

Comment: another java's basics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: it wasn't my answer ... it was you with a little help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , from the help of @Selvin I implemented the `equals` method which I posted in my question. And I replaced the `==` comparator to the `equals` method.